# ruby - why don't blocks inherit their caller's $SAFE level like methods?

Tags: ruby, scope, global-variables, block

When a method is called by a thread with $SAFE = 4, that method is run with the same $SAFE level:

```
def test_method
  raise "value of $SAFE inside the method: #{$SAFE}"
end
t = Thread.new{$SAFE = 4; self.test_method}; t.join
 => RuntimeError: value of $SAFE inside the method: 4
```

However, when a block is called, it seems to use the $SAFE from its original context instead:

```
test_lambda = lambda do
  raise "value of $SAFE inside the lambda: #{$SAFE}"
end
t = Thread.new{$SAFE = 4; test_lambda.call}; t.join
 => RuntimeError: value of $SAFE inside the lambda: 0
```

Can someone explain why it works this way?  It seems like a security problem.

(the reason I'm using `raise` instead of `puts` is that `puts` doesn't work at $SAFE = 4)

This can be used to eval a tainted string in a seemingly safe context:

```
test_lambda = lambda{|s| puts "Tainted: #{s.tainted?}"; eval s}
t = Thread.new{$SAFE = 4; test_lambda.call("puts `date`")}; t.join
=> Tainted: true
=> Fri Mar 30 03:15:33 UTC 2012
```

Comment: Wouldn't a closure capture the value at the time of definition?

Comment: Are you able to execute actions within the block that a `$SAFE` level of 0 would allow?

Comment: Andrew: yes.  Replacing the contents of the lambda with something like `puts \`hostname\`` causes it to do exactly that from within the $SAFE = 4 thread.  I understand this behavior from a scope perspective (kinda) -- I'm just wondering whether $SAFE is completely broken in this regard.

Comment: I don't think it is. You can only execute statements that you prepared outside the safe level.

Are you able to "taint" the proc by passing an argument that's potentially unsafe into it?

Comment: @JoePym: I think so.  I added a new example that shows how the lambda can be made to eval a string created at $SAFE = 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because a lambda operates with the scope it was defined at (including all the local variables!)

Hence, you defined the lambda at safe level 0, and it therefore executed at that level when it was called, as that's what the state of the variable was.